# Ubuntu Server 21.10 - How to use iPhone USB tethering?

Tags: usb, raspberrypi, iphone, 21.10, tethering

I'm trying to use my iPhone as Hotspot via USB (tethering) in Ubuntu Server 21.10 installed on Raspberry Pi 4: unsuccessfully so far.

I installed the following packages as found on internet:

```
sudo apt-get install ipheth-utils libimobiledevice-dev libimobiledevice-utils
```

Then, I'm connecting my iPhone via USB to the Raspberry Pi, but it's not working.
I tried to reboot, and to `sudo netplan apply` , but it's still not working.

Information about my config:

- Raspberry Pi 4
- Ubuntu Server 21.10
- iPhone 12 iOS 15.0.2

When I run `ip a` , here is the output I got:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:5f:01:4c:a6:f0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:5f:01:4c:a6:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: enx92fd6113afb3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 92:fd:61:13:af:b3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.6/24 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

When I run `lsusb`

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. iPhone 5/5C/5S/6/SE
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Current kernel:

- 5.13.0-1008-raspi